# Gaussian Binomial Coefficent applied to Projective space

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Can the formula for calculating the number of linear subspaces of a vector space using Gaussian binomial coefficent be applied to linear subspaces of projective space also (assuming a finite field)?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I've just tried using the general formula for those coefficents, but that's all (I'm quite new to algebraic geometry so don't know too much yet).

Comment: (Your question has almost nothing to do with algebraic geometry) You want to count subspaces of a projective space... can you relate that number to the number of linear subspaces of some vector space?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez will it not just be that the dimension of the vector space is one more than the dimension of the projective space?

Comment: But what does that have to do with the subspaces?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm not sure apart from the fact that a subspace dimension can't exceed that of the vector space. I'll look at some more references first etc.

Comment: if $P$ is the projective space associated to a vector space $V$, is there a sensible way of assigning to each subspace of $V$ a subspaces of $P$?

Comment: I'm not too sure. I'm just getting confused I'll try and reread some notes and see if it helps. I haven't ever actually done projective geometry which doesn't help (I've learnt what projective space is today).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I've been thinking about this and can I not count the number of subspaces of say $P^{n-1}$ as being made up of a disjoint union of an Affine space of the same dimension and a hyperplane at infinity of dimension one less.

which generalises to give the formula $ \frac{q^{n} -1}{q-1} $

But won't this only give the number of 1 dimensional subspaces?